# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in scheme at index 0: AND android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android-emulator

This problems occur when I click on Login button on the android emulator, it appear on Username textbox.

Kindly help me to resolve it...your help is appreciate ~

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in scheme at index 0:

android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

--
Update 7.9.2011

I post my code over here:

http://pastebin.com/EX0ArwaE --> Login.java

http://pastebin.com/WgGctGHN --> CustomHttpClient.java

Comment: Can you please provide the relevant code and the full stack traces?

Comment: Julian, do you means the java code?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise we can only guess what you're trying to do.

Comment: Julian, I already make update for my question and here is my php code : http://pastebin.com/7wYcYDys --> check.php

Answer (score 1):

So first the Android stuff: You're getting this `NetworkOnMainThreadException` because you're trying to make a HTTP request on your main application thread which is the UI thread. You shouldn't do any blocking operations in this thread. Use an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead.

I'm not quite sure what's causing the `IllegalArgumentException` but I guess it's this line:

```
response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/es/check.php", postParameters);
```

You have probably changed the URL (localhost usually doesn't make sense on a phone). The scheme part is the `http`. Maybe you have something like `" http://..."` (note the leading space character) in the original code?

Short note on the PHP:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * from people WHERE username = "' .$_POST['un'] . '" and password = "' .md5($_POST['pw']) . '"';
```

That's what you call an [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

**Update:** Here's some example. Didn't test it, hopefully it works.

```
public class LoginLayout extends Activity {

    EditText un,pw;
    TextView error;
    Button ok;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        un=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_un);
        pw=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_pw);
        ok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        error=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_error);

        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new LoginTask().execute(un.getText().toString(), pw.getText().toString());
            }

        });
    }

    private class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Object> {

        protected Object doInBackground(String... params) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", params[0]));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", params[1]));

            String response = null;

            try {
                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/es/check.php", postParameters);
                String res = response.toString();
                res = res.replaceAll("\\s+","");
                return res;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return e;
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            if (result instanceof String) {
                if (result.equals("1")) {
                    error.setText("Correct Username or Password");
                } else {
                    error.setText("Sorry!! Wrong Username or Password Entered");
                }
            } else if (result instanceof Exception) {
                un.setText(result.toString());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Julian...I try it already but its gt error at the last paragraph: else if (result instanceof Exception) {
                    un.setText(e.toString());
                }     at the (e.toString());

Comment: thanks again Julian, the java code I think don't have any problem. The problem now occur is on my check.php url.

Comment: One problem I see (besides the SQL Injection which you really should fix, use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)) is that you're sending `username` and `password` but in the PHP script you try to access `un` and `pw`:

Comment: izzit now my coding should be like that : $sql = 'SELECT * from people WHERE username = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) . '" and password = "' . $_POST['password'] . '"';

Comment: @RYS Yeah, but I guess you still want to hash the password. ;)

Comment: Ok, try tp find out myself.Thanks you so much Julian. Thanks for your helping. Have a nice day. =)